# Extracting an edge set from a tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting, graph, kruskals-algorithm

I have created the following program. It takes an input G, which consists of the vertices of a graph, along with the edges and the corresponding edge weights. The aim of  the program is to extract just the edges

```
def edges(G):     
    E =[]     
    for i in G[1]:         
        E.append(i[0])     
    return E  
print (edges(G))
```

On the following input

```
G = [({'a', 'b'}, 4), ({'a', 'c'}, 6), ({'a', 'd'}, 8), ({'b', 'e'}, 1) ,
      ({'b', 'f'}, 9), ({'c', 'f'}, 3), ({'d', 'g'}, 7), ({'d', 'h'}, 0)]
```

The following output is produced:

```
[{'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'd'}, {'e', 'b'}, {'f', 'b'}, {'f', 'c'}, {'g', 'd'}, {'h', 'd'}]
```

The output I am trying to get is:

```
[{'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'd'}, {'b', 'e'}, {'b', 'f'}, {'c', 'f'}, {'d', 'g'}, {'d', 'h'}]
```

Can anyone explain why the tuples I have extracted are reordered?

Comment: Well, these are not tuples. You have a lists of sets, which are unordered collections.

Comment: list(zip(*G))[0].. in case you want a 1 liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set` is an [unordered collection](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). What you are requesting is not possible.

The best you can do is use an ordered collection, such as `list` or `tuple`. Below is an example.

```
res = [tuple(sorted(x[0])) for x in G]

print(res)

[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'g'), ('d', 'h')]
```

---

This is also possible functionally, but messy since Python has no native function composition. For composition, you can use 3rd party library [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
from operator import itemgetter
from toolz import compose

res = list(map(compose(tuple, sorted, itemgetter(0)), G))
```

Comment: @timgeb, Yes, IMO should be part of the standard library. It has benefits (e.g. parsing docstrings, etc) which would be messy to implement yourself.